# How to revert a converted text string back to original HTML layout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, split, jquery-selectors

This question is derived from the accepted answer of [Jquery - How to replace one word in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975831/jquery-how-to-replace-one-word-in-a-div/32975947)

The code below will detect a specific word in a `<div>`, change the detected word into another word, and then render the everything in the `<div>` using the `.text()` method.  Although this is a viable solution, is there perhaps a way to automatically convert the text string back to the original HTML layout format while retaining the newly created text string?

That is to say, the new output should maintain the line breaks`<br/>`, but it should not be limited to them only (all HTML should be kept).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dealer-addy">
    8726 N. Royal Ln<br>
    Irving, TX  75063<br>
    email@aol.com
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var text = $(".dealer-addy").text(); 

function extractEmails ( text ){
    return text.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi) ;
}

var email = extractEmails(text);
var value = $(".dealer-addy").text();

value = value.replace(email, "new@email.com"); 
$(".dealer-addy").text(value);
```

**Output:**

```
8726 N. Royal Ln Irving, TX 75063 new@email.com
```

**Desired Output:**

```
8726 N. Royal Ln<br/>
Irving, TX 75063<br/>
new@email.com
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VS7Qe/166/)

```js
var text = $(".dealer-addy").text(); 

function extractEmails ( text ){
    return text.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi) ;
}

var email = extractEmails(text);
var value = $(".dealer-addy").text();

value = value.replace(email, "new@email.com"); 
$(".dealer-addy").text(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dealer-addy">
  8726 N. Royal Ln<br>
  Irving, TX 75063<br>
  email@aol.com
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use jQuery.html instead of text.

```
var text = $(".dealer-addy").html(); 

function extractEmails ( text ){
    return text.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi) ;
}

var email = extractEmails(text);
var value = $(".dealer-addy").html();

value = value.replace(email, "new@email.com"); 
$(".dealer-addy").html(value);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pyfbfuo9/

Comment: Thanks that was quick and efficient.  Do you typically have a rule of thumb to know when to use .html() and when to use .text()?

Comment: $.html() delivers you the entire HTML code below the entity, $.text() "Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants." -> but not the HTML tags. So if you want to keep the HTML tags, use html, if you expect text only, use text.